# Building up an array in numpy/scipy by iteration in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Often, I am building an array by iterating through some data, e.g.:

```
my_array = []
for n in range(1000):
  # do operation, get value 
  my_array.append(value)
# cast to array
my_array = array(my_array)
```

I find that I have to first build a list and then cast it (using "array") to an array. Is there a way around these? All these casting calls clutter the code... how can I iteratively build up "my_array", with it being an array from the start?

Comment: what happens if you don't do it?

Comment: The reason numpy is so fast in the first place is that it operates with constant size arrays and not dynamic lists. 

So getting rid of it just to reduce "clutter" in your code is probably not the right way to go. 

If you know the size beforehand (1000) preallocate it. If you don't - building up the list is definitely the best way to go, as python lists [] are pretty efficient.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
# the array passed into your function
ax = NP.random.randint(10, 99, 20).reshape(5, 4)

# just define a function to operate on some data
fnx = lambda x : NP.sum(x)**2

# apply the function directly to the numpy array
new_row = NP.apply_along_axis(func1d=fnx, axis=0, arr=ax)

# 'append' the new values to the original array
new_row = new_row.reshape(1,4)
ax = NP.vstack((ax, new_row))
```

Comment: As this is the accepted answer I have to say this:
I have seen vstack used a lot like this. One should be aware that this is really(!) non-performant. If you do build up a big array this way you do a lot of unnecessary memory copy operation. see answers below

Answer (score 36):

NumPy provides a 'fromiter' method:

```
def myfunc(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i**2


np.fromiter(myfunc(5), dtype=int)
```

which yields

```
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Comment: When using `np.fromiter` and you know the size of the array beforehand, you can pass it as a parameter so the array gets pre-allocated. This increases performance immensely. So in the example above, do: `np.fromiter(myfunc(5), dtype=int, count=5)`

Answer (score 19):

The recommended way to do this is to preallocate before the loop and use slicing and indexing to insert

```
my_array = numpy.zeros(1,1000)
for i in xrange(1000):
    #for 1D array
    my_array[i] = functionToGetValue(i)
    #OR to fill an entire row
    my_array[i:] = functionToGetValue(i)
    #or to fill an entire column
    my_array[:,i] = functionToGetValue(i)
```

numpy *does* provide an `array.resize()` method, but this will be far slower due to the cost of reallocating memory inside a loop. If you *must* have flexibility, then I'm afraid the only way is to create an `array` from a `list`.

EDIT: If you are worried that you're allocating too much memory for your data, I'd use the method above to over-allocate and then when the loop is done, lop off the unused bits of the array using `array.resize()`. This will be *far*, *far* faster than constantly reallocating the array inside the loop.

EDIT: In response to @user248237's comment, assuming you know any one dimension of the array (for simplicity's sake):

```
my_array = numpy.array(10000, SOMECONSTANT)

for i in xrange(someVariable):
    if i >= my_array.shape[0]:
        my_array.resize((my_array.shape[0]*2, SOMECONSTANT))

    my_array[i:] = someFunction()

#lop off extra bits with resize() here
```

The general principle is "allocate more than you think you'll need, and if things change, resize the array as few times as possible". Doubling the size could be thought of as excessive, but in fact this is the method used by several data structures in several standard libraries in other languages (`java.util.Vector` does this by default for example. I think several implementations of `std::vector` in C++ do this as well).

Comment: What if I don't know the size ahead of time?

Comment: That makes sense, but suppose I built up arrays this way by allocating more than I need -- how can I then iterate over the array? If I allocate numpy.zeros(1, 1000) but only use 50 elements, I don't want to iterate until I hit a zero... the approach of overallocating seems to create this weird situation where each array data type will require a different "stop" condition for looping.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: As I said, you can make a final call to `resize()` when the loop is done. If you shrink the array to the correct size, you will throw away all the zero elements.

Comment: Someone should write something akin to the stl::vector approach where is allocated blocks as things get appended. . .

Comment: The [Python array module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array) module can do this, for discussion see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950456/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array).

Answer (score 0):

Building up the array using `list.append()` seems to be much faster than any kind of dynamic resizing of a Numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

class ndarray_builder:
  
  def __init__(self, capacity_step, column_count):
    self.capacity_step = capacity_step
    self.column_count = column_count
    self.arr = np.empty((self.capacity_step, self.column_count))
    self.row_pointer = 0

  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.close()
  
  def append(self, row):
    if self.row_pointer == self.arr.shape[0]:
      self.arr.resize((self.arr.shape[0] + self.capacity_step, self.column_count))
    self.arr[self.row_pointer] = row
    self.row_pointer += 1
  
  def close(self):
    self.arr.resize((self.row_pointer, self.column_count))

def with_builder():
  with ndarray_builder(1000, 2) as b:
    for i in range(10000):
      b.append((1, 2))
      b.append((3, 4))
  return b.arr

def without_builder():
  b = []
  for i in range(10000):
    b.append((1, 2))
    b.append((3, 4))
  return np.array(b)

print(f'without_builder: {timeit.timeit(without_builder, number=1000)}')
print(f'with_builder: {timeit.timeit(with_builder, number=1000)}')
```

```
without_builder: 3.4763141250000444
with_builder: 7.960973499999909
```