# Appending arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a loop that reads through a file until the end is reached. On each pass through the loop, I extract a 1D numpy array. I want to append this array to another numpy array in the 2D direction. That is, I might read in something of the form

```
x = [1,2,3]
```

and I want to append it to something of the form

```
z = [[0,0,0],
     [1,1,1]]
```

I know I can simply do `z = numpy.append([z],[x],axis = 0)` and achieve my desired result of

```
z = [[0,0,0],
     [1,1,1],
     [1,2,3]]
```

My issue comes from the fact that in the first run through the loop, I don't have anything to append to yet because first array read in is the first row of the 2D array. I dont want to have to write an if statement to handle the first case because that is ugly. If I were working with lists I could simply do `z = []` before the loop and every time I read in an array, simply do `z.append(x)` to achieve my desired result. However I can find no way doing a similar procedure in numpy. I can create an empty numpy array, but then I can't append to it in the way I want. Can anyone help? Am I making any sense?

EDIT:

After some more research, I found another workaround that does technically do what I want although I think I will go with the solution given by @Roger Fan given that numpy appending is very slow. I'm posting it here just so its out there.

I can still define `z = []` at the beginning of the loop. Then append my arrays with `np.append(z, x). This will ultimately give me something like

```
z = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3]
```

Then, because all the arrays I read in are of the same size, after the loop I can simply resize with `np.resize(n, m)' and get what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @heltonbiker mentioned in his answer, something like `np.genfromtext` is going to be the best way to do this if it fits your needs. Otherwise, I suggest reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649788/optimal-way-to-append-to-numpy-array/25649863#25649863) about appending to numpy arrays. Basically, numpy array appending is extremely slow and should be avoided whenever possible. There are two much better (and faster by about 20x) solutions:

If you know the length in advance, you can preallocate your array and assign to it.

```
length_of_file = 5000
results = np.empty(length_of_file)
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        results[i] = processing_func(line)
```

Otherwise, just keep a list of lists or list of arrays and convert it to a numpy array all at once.

```
results = []
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        results.append(processing_func(line))
results = np.array(results)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it. Read the whole file into one array, using for example `numpy.genfromtext()`.

With this one array, you can then loop over the rows, loop over the columns, and perform other operations using slices.

Alternatively, you can create a regular list, append a lot of arrays to that list, and in the end generate your desired array from the list using either `numpy.array(list_of_arrays)` or, for more control, `numpy.vstack(list_of_arrays)`.

The idea in this second approach is "delayed array creation": find and organize your data first, and then create the desired array once, already in its final form.

Comment: I have to loop till the end of the file because the file has somewhat of a complicated structure such that numpy doesn't have a generic method capable of reading it. I already have my own method of reading in the file and it is perfectly fine, I just want to implement what I've asked in my question so it is "nicer".

Comment: Then I would suggest using the second approach in my answer.