# Python: quickest way to sort list and keep indexes

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, sorting

I am trying to find the quickest way to sort a list.
For example, say i was trying to sort the following list

```
lst = [1, 0, -1, 0.1, 0, 5, 10, 4]
```

What i want at the end, is to have the sorted list, but to also be able to know what their indexes in `lst` were, before the sorting.

The method i am currently using is this

```
lst = [1, 0, -1, 0.1, 0, 5, 10, 4]
lst = list(enumerate(lst))
lst.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

Doing so will give `lst = [(6, 10), (5, 5), (7, 4), (0, 1), (3, 0.1), (1, 0), (4, 0), (2, -1)]`

Now i do not necessarily need to have the tuple (idx, value), it can be two separate lists. The important part, is to sort the values, and also know what were the 'original' indexes in the list `lst`. So for example get:

```
lst_val = [10, 5, 4, 1, 0.1, 0, 0, -1]
lst_idx = [6, 5, 7, 0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Now i was wondering if there was maybe a quicker/more efficient method to sort this way, because i could have a list with over 200,000 values inside it.

Using `numpy` is allowed, but besides that i don't think other modules are allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/transpose-unzip-function-inverse-of-zip)

Comment: @quamrana not really, i am trying to sort the list, and also keep track of the indexes, not trying to separate indexes from the list...

Comment: The answer points out that `zip` is its own inverse. You have made a `list` which is as if you have zipped the values and their indexes together. Now you need to unzip them into two lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a significant speed up you must use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

np_lst = np.array(lst)

sorted_indices = np_lst.argsort() #array([2, 1, 4, 3, 0, 7, 5, 6])
```

Then, you can 'sort' the array this way:

```
np_lst[sorted_indices]
#array([-1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.1,  1. ,  4. ,  5. , 10. ])
```

You can also get it in reverse with:

```
np_lst[sorted_indices[::-1]] 
#array([10. ,  5. ,  4. ,  1. ,  0.1,  0. ,  0. , -1. ])
```

Comment: Say i have a list that has 200,000 values inside of it, would it still be quicker to use your method if i have to convert the list to a `numpy array`, by doing `lst = np.array(lst)`, and then sorting with `np.sort`?

Comment: @needle im pretty sure the speed up is significant

Comment: do you think it would be even quicker if i create lst as a `numpy array`, and update the values to the numpy array instead?

Comment: @needle I don't understand what do you mean with "create lst as a numpy array"

Comment: @needle you could create another question about that or edit this question

Comment: In reality, i start from an empty list `lst=[]`. Then i have to open a file, and i add the values to the list using `append` (it's a bit more complicated, but its the gist of what im doing). After that, i need to sort the values, and also know the indexes.        And the question is, would it be quicker to keep doing like before, and when im about to sort, do `lst = np.array(lst)` and then use your sorting method. OR, would it be faster to immediately create the list as `lst = np.array([])`, and add the values to that, and then sort.

Comment: @needle--from [Fastest way to grow a numpy numeric array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array) it would be faster to grow the Python list then convert to numpy array before the sort rather than growing a numpy array.

Comment: @needle always is a bad idea using `numpy.append` iteratively. Try something like this instead: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Countn't you use `lst_val = sorted(lst)` then use `.index()` to find the index of the values. Something like this:

```
lst = [1, 0, -1, 0.1, 0, 5, 10, 4]
lst_val = sorted(lst)
lst_idx = []

for i in lst_val:
    lst_idx.append(lst.index(i))
```

Comment: no no, `.index` is `O(n)`, so this is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I guess you can do the for loop in one line

Comment: What do you mean doing loop in one line? How does it change the complexity of the loop?

Comment: change it up a bit and use `list()`

Comment: The thing is i pretty much know how to sort, but i am trying to find the quickest way to do so. I need to sort the values, and also the indexes. I am trying to figure out how to do so, so that the program can execute itself faster...

Comment: I don't really think it would be possible to do it any faster than two lines

Comment: By faster i mean the program's execution time, not the number of lines it takes to write the code.

Comment: yeah I get what you mean, I think using numpy would be the fastest in terms of code and computing but that means you need to import numpy which takes time.

Comment: yea, i'll try to see if it is quicker to use numpy. Thanks for the tips